# check_batch_request_status response only 5 products error

Tags: facebook, catalog

I use this API to check how many products got error when submit to Catalog.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/check_batch_request_status/

Example:
When I excute submit batch with 30 products within 10 products have errors, but that API response only 5 products have errors.

How can I get 5 products error left?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbjuS.png

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. If you follow the link from that documentation page to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/check-batch-request-status/, there it says, _“errors: List of sample errors(does not include all errors)”_, so that appears to be on purpose, that you only get a sample of the errors, and not all of them.

Comment: I wondering how can I get all errors.
And I don't know how to get all errors via load_ids_of_invalid_requests they're mention on document.

Comment: Or if that is possible, Can you give me a better solution to resolve that. Thank a ton, hihi

Comment: Well you would just add `load_ids_of_invalid_requests=true` or `load_ids_of_invalid_requests=1` to your request parameters.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ab704b073be27177e68b35f7b0e077fd

Wow amazing, this is work but how can I get full errors include id and message of error.